# Azure Batch Job: Is there a code example for batch jobs created by using User Subscription

Tags: azure-batch

All the examples I have seen so far user "Batch services" is there any code example for "User Subscription"?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/ArticleProjects

Answer (score 0):

Submitting jobs for User Subscription Azure Batch accounts is no different from that of Batch Service Azure Batch accounts; only the method for obtaining authentication/credentials for the service client differs. You can view [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth) for more information - there are code samples at the bottom of the article for C#/.NET.

Comment: I would have to disagree on that because obvious thinks like cloudServiceConfiguration: new CloudServiceConfiguration(osFamily: "4") would not work in User Subscription. I cannot used the example given in git and just change the authentication and expect the whole thing to work. It is not just that simple

Comment: `CloudServiceConfiguration` is something defined at the pool level and not the job level. Your question pertains to Batch jobs, where there is no difference between pool allocation modes. Please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics#account) for more information and the restrictions imposed by User Subscription Batch accounts.